# GZip Compression between Java and AS3?

Tags: java, json, actionscript-3, gzip

How would one compress a byte array byte[] in java and then uncompress it in as3 and vice-versa?
Can someone provide example code?
I am trying to transfer JSON strings between the 2 platform but JSON has a large overheard and I see it can be compressed.

So far I've come across the following to use:
GZipOutputStream in Java and ByteArray.uncompress in AS3

Maybe there is a better compression algorithm. I looked into the ByteArray class of AS3 and I don't see gzip as a supported algorithm.

Comment: Why do people downvote questions without saying why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use the zlib format on both ends (as opposed to gzip), since as noted, the [AS3 ByteArray class](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/utils/ByteArray.html#uncompress%28%29) supports it directly.

On the Java end, use the [Deflater](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/zip/Deflater.html) class in java.util.zip.

Answer (score 1):

AS3 ByteArray has inbuilt support for [ZLIB](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc1950.txt) and [DEFLATE](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc1951.txt)

A simple [Google](http://www.google.com) search produced this for gzip encoding / decoding: http://probertson.com/projects/gzipencoder/

You can find the source code [here](http://code.google.com/p/ascompress/)

However, java seems to have inbuilt zlib and deflate en / decoding in the `java.util.zip` package. I suggest you use something commonly built into both AS3 and java